# Heroku deploying jar problems

Tags: heroku, jar

So, I'm trying to deploy a .jar file on Heroku. When I try to deploy it I get this error:

### JAR file must have a .jar or .war extension.

I don't know what's going on, I downloaded the java plugin, I downloaded the Heroku CLI plugin.Idk what to do, here's the deploy command.

heroku deploy:jar C:\Users\My Name\Desktop\Tester Bot2\myfile.jar --app mybotapp

Comment: the space character in CLI has a special meaning. It separates strings. You need to put quotation marks around your path. Furthermore the backslash character is the escape character. If you want to use backslash you need to escape it. `heroku deploy:jar "C:\\Users\\My Name\\Desktop\\Tester Bot2\\myfile.jar" --app mybotapp`

Answer (score 0):

You need to escape backslashes and use quotation marks for your path:

```
heroku deploy:jar "C:\\Users\\My Name\\Desktop\\Tester Bot2\\myfile.jar" --app mybotapp
```